# Can you create an NSValue from a C struct with bitfields?

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, objective-c-runtime, bit-fields

I'm trying to do the following, but `NSValue`'s creation method returns `nil`.
Are C bitfields in structs not supported?

```
struct MyThingType {
    BOOL isActive:1;
    uint count:7;
} myThing = {
    .isActive = YES,
    .count = 3,
};

NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&myThing objCType:@encode(struct MyThingType)];
// value is nil here
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove the bitfield specifiers?

Comment: Interesting question, but I'd just advise you not use bitfields at all.

Comment: why bother using a bitfield when you are anyway adding the overhead of putting it into a NSValue ?

Comment: @claptrap: Great point... I hope you don't mind my adding it to my answer

Answer (score 6):

First and foremost, claptrap makes a very good point in his comment: why bother using bitfield specifiers (which are mainly used to *either* do micro-optimization or manually add padding bits where you need them), to *then* wrap it all up in an instance of `NSValue`).
It's like buying a castle, but then living in the kitchen to not ware out the carpets...

I don't think it is, a quick canter through the apple dev-docs [came up with this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingctypes.html)... there are indeed several issues to take into account when it comes to bit fields.

I've also just found [this](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/28773-bug-in-nsvalue-was-re-encode-ambiguity-nsvalue-internals.html), which explains *why* bit-fields + `NSValue` don't really play well together.
Especially in cases where the `sizeof` a struct can lead to `NSValue` reading the data in an... shall we say erratic manner:
The struct you've created is padded to 8 bits. Now these bits could be read as 2 `int`, or 1 `long` or something... From what I've read on the linked page, it's not unlikely that this is what is happening.
So, basically, `NSValue` is incapable of determining the actual types, when you're using bit fields. In case of ambiguity, an int (width 4 in most cases) is assumed and under/overflow occurs, and you have a mess on your hands.

Since the compiler still has *some* liberty as to where what member is actually stored, it doesn't quite suffice to pass the stringified typedef sort of thing (`objCType: @encode(struct YourStruct`), because there is a good chance that you won't be able to make sense of the actual struct itself, owing to compiler optimizations and such...

I'd suggest you simply drop the bit field specifiers, because structs *should* be supported... at least, last time I tried, a struct with simple primitive types worked just fine.

Comment: Not all code that reads `@encode` is capable of handling all type that `@encode` can describe. Not all types can be correctly described by `@encode`.

Comment: You may want to use NSData instead of NSValue to wrap this struct.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with a union. Simply put the structure into union that has another member with a type supported by `NSValue` and has a size larger than your structure. In your case this is obvious for `long`.

```
union _bitfield_word_union
{
  yourstructuretype bitfield;
  long plain;
};
```

You can make it more robust against resizing the structure by using an array whose size is calculated at compile time. (Please remember that `sizeof()` is a compile time operator, too.)

```
char plain[(sizeof(yourstructuretype)/sizeof(char)];
```

Then you can store the structure with the bitfield into the union and read the `plain` member out.

```
union converter = { .bitfield = yourstructuretypevalue };
long plain = converter.plain;
```

Use this value for `NSValue` instance creation. Reading out you have to do the inverse way.

I'm pretty sure that through a technical correctum of C99 this became standard conforming (called type punning), because you can expect that reading out a member's value (`bitfield`) through another members value (`plain`) and storing it back is defined, if the member being read is at least as big as the member being written. (There might be undefined bits 9-31/63 in `plain`, but you do not have to care about it.) However it is real-world conforming.

Dirty hack? Maybe. One might call it C99. However using bitfields in combination with `NSValue` sounds like using dirty hacks.